# Finding $E(X-Y)$ given $f_{X,Y}(x, y)=\frac{y}{x^2}I_{0 \lt y \lt x \lt 2}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint density:
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases} {\frac{y}{x^2}}  & \text{$0 \lt y \lt
>  x \lt 2$} \\{0} & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Give the value of $E(X−Y)$.

By linearity of expectation, $E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)$. I started by obtaining the marginal distributions. I will let software do the computations as I am mainly concerned that I'm understanding the concept correctly.

$$\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)
&= \int_y^2\frac{y}{x^2}dx\\\\
&= \left(-\frac{y}{2}+1\right)I_{(0,2)}(y) \\\\
f_X(x)
&= \int_0^x\frac{y}{x^2}dy\\\\
&= \frac{1}{2}I_{(0,2)}(x) \\\\
\end{align*}$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
E(Y)
&= \int_0^2y\left(-\frac{y}{2}+1\right)dy\\\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \\\\
E(X)
&= \int_0^2x\cdot\frac{1}{2}dx\\\\
&= 1 \\\\
\end{align*}$$

Finally,

$$E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)=1-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Is this a valid solution? I would also be interested in seeing alternative approaches.

Comment: Not sure why the allignment is weird. If someone could fix that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It´s a valid solution. I would have calculated it the same way.

Comment: It is right and the easiest way I can think of. An alternative approach might be to calculate the PDF of $X-Y$ and then take the expectation value, but that would take longer here.